# Finding the Riemann curvature tensor with sympy.diffgeom

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to determine the Riemann curvature tensor with the symbolic expression for the metric g. I have pre-calculated the metric. The cartesian coordinates are given as

- x = x(eta,theta,psi) = a*sinh(eta)*cos(psi)/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta))
- y = y(eta,theta,psi) = a*sinh(eta)*sin(psi)/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta))
- z = z(eta,theta,psi) = a*sin(theta))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta))

The metric is found from transformation from Cartesian (x,y,z) to Toroidal coordinates (eta,theta,psi). Using the symbolic package SymPy, the following script

```
from sympy.diffgeom import Manifold, Patch, CoordSystem, TensorProduct
from sympy.abc import theta, eta, psi
import sympy as sym

x,y,z,a = sym.symbols("x y z a")
m = Manifold("M",3)
patch = Patch("P",m)

cartesian = CoordSystem("cartesian",patch)
toroidal = CoordSystem("toroidal",patch)

from sympy import sin,cos,sinh,cosh
toroidal.connect_to(cartesian,[eta,theta,psi],
[(a*sinh(eta)*cos(psi))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta)),
 (a*sinh(eta)*sin(psi))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta)),
 (a*sin(theta))/(cosh(eta) - cos(theta))],inverse=False)

g = sym.Matrix([[a**2/(cos(theta) - cosh(eta))**2,        0,           0],
                [0,           a**2/(cos(theta) - cosh(eta)),           0],
                [0,   0,   a**2*sinh(eta)**2/(cos(theta) - cosh(eta))**2]])

diff_forms = toroidal.base_oneforms()
metric_diff_form = sum([TensorProduct(di, dj)*g[i, j] for i, di in enumerate(diff_forms) for j, dj in enumerate(diff_forms)])

from sympy.diffgeom import metric_to_Riemann_components
metric_to_Riemann_components(metric_diff_form)
```

produces the result

```
((((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))),
 (((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))),
 (((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)),
  ((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))))
```

The result is incorrect for the given metric g. The result should be non-trivial.

Comment: I managed to find a mistake in the metric. The g_22 component is wrong. Fixing that, and following the advice(s) below, I am still getting the trivial result described above.

Comment: The metric is supposed to be as following : `g = sym.Matrix([[a**2/(cos(theta) - cosh(eta))**2,    0,  0],
                [0, a**2/(cos(theta) - cosh(eta))**2,     0],
                [0, 0, a**2*sinh(eta)**2/(cos(theta) - cosh(eta))**2]])` . Here is the corrected version of the script : http://paste.ofcode.org/BhhgvEHGePrRHW57HHGGGX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare *eta, theta, phi* as coordinate functions, that is:

```
eta, theta, phi = toroidal.coord_functions()
```

The *coordinate functions* are the scalar variables to use in the *diffgeom* module.
Furthermore, I suggest to declare the coordinate function strings when you declare the coordinate system:

```
toroidal = CoordSystem("toroidal", patch, ["eta", "theta", "psi"])
```

The derivation of the Riemann components is attained by derivations over the *coordinate functions*, which are variables of their own types (i.e. they are not instances *Symbol*). Any *Symbol* instance, even if with the same name of a *coordinate function*, is considered different and constant under derivation. Thus the result is zero.

Re-declare your matrix with these variables, and it should work out.

Comment: I am getting non trivial results now! I also noticed that if the metric is pre-defined with sympy.abc eta, theta, psi, the results again become trivial. I have to use these variables defined as 'sympy.diffgeom.diffgeom.BaseScalarField' objects.

Comment: The toroidal.connect_to() function call causes an exception AttributeError: 'BaseScalarField' object has no attribute 'as_dummy'.

Comment: I think you need to use symbols with connect_to(), not BaseScalarField.

Comment: There also seem to be an issue with simplify and trigsimp on the entries of the curvature tensor. AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'is_Rational'. I managed to get around this by converting each entry to a string and then performing simplify on the string expression.